# configurable products attributes not showing in layered navigation unless saved

Tags: ce-1.7.0.2, attributes, configurable-product, layered-navigation, magmi

I have imported a large amount of configurable products via Magmi. However even after reindexing the whole site via SSH to avoid timeout issues, the attirbutes tied to the configurable products won't show on the layered navigation unless you go into the product in the backend and save it.

This would be fine if it wasn't for the 5,000 products I'd need to do this for. Is there any script or automated way I can fix this.

Comment: We may need a bit more information here as to how you are importing the products, what attributes you are dealing with, how the attributes are set up etc. Without this information it will be hard to debug this.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about third party module support.

Comment: @Marius -  disagree - this problems can arise with any external import.

Comment: @benmarks. Any external import...so a third party module. But you can leave this open. I just expressed my opinion. It's a year old question with no answers. I doubt it will be answered

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried mass product actions? You can select, say 100 products on the grid, choose mass action "change attributes" and save some attribute like Status=Active. This may trigger attribute reindex.